# Google Forms - get multiple choice response's index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form with several multiple choice questions which have textual answers.
I can loop all questions in the form and get the text values of the answer using:

```
for(var i in headers) {
  message += e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
}
```

However, I would also like to retrieve the index of each selected answer in order to provide a score.

Just to be clear - if I have the following multiple choice question in my form:

What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

With the answers being:

- 5
- 3
- European or African?

If the submitter answered 'European or African?' I would like to get the index of that response - namely the number 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use class FormResponse (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

and method ItemResponse.asMultipleChoiceItem (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asMultipleChoiceItem())

and method MultipleChoiceItem.getIndex() (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#getIndex())

Answer (score 0):

The `MultipleChoiceItem.getIndex()` method is still getting the **index of the multiple choice question item**, not the **selected index of the multiple-choice response**. To get the index of the selected choice, use `MultipleChoiceItem.getChoices()`, then loop through the `choices[]` array to compare the selected choice with each value of the `choices[]` array. If the choice value = selected choice, get the index of the array as the selected choice index:

```
// Add this function to 'on form submit' trigger.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var selectChoiceIndex = getSelectedChoiceIndex(e);
}

function getSelectedChoiceIndex(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var mChoiceIndex = 1; // Assuming 1 is your mutiple-choice question index.
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  var selectedChoice = itemResponses[mChoiceIndex].getResponse();
  var choices = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[mChoiceIndex].asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices();

  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (selectedChoice == choices[i]) {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
```

**Things to note:**

1. Example given in this answer is **just a concept**, not an optimized or fully tested version of the code.
2. `mChoiceIndex` here is the index of the same **[ItemType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type)** on the form. It follows the sequence of how they're presented **during run-time**, not design-time, especially when you have conditional page-break/section.

Comment: I had a similar use case and google led me here.  I don't think this works exactly as written.  `selectedChoice` is a string, and `choices[i]` is an object of type `Choice`, so they will never match.  Changing the condition to `selectedChoice == choices[i].getValue()` worked for me.